# Adding UTM Zone Number to Coordinates using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, utm

The computer program that I'm working with requires an 8 digit UTM Easting for the coordinates of shapefiles (i.e., the UTM zone number must be included with each coordinate within a shapefile).  The program was designed in Europe and considers all of my shapefiles to be extremely far away, due to the two "missing" digits.

I'm using ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reproject your shapefiles to a new coordinate system. There are several methods to do this in ArcGIS. One method is to use [Project (Data Management) tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000).

As target coordinate system you have to use a coordinate system which includes the zone numbers. For some regions there are already coordinate systems defined in ArcGIS with these zone numbers.
E.g for Germany:
ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N_8stellen
(“8stellen” means “8 digits” for x coordinate instead of 6 without zone number)

If ArcGIS has no coordinate system with zone number for your region you have to define your own coordinate system with zone numbers:

- Use a .PRJ File (with our coordinate system without zone numbers)
- Change FalseEasting parameter from 500000 to 32500000 (for zone 32)
- Save it as new .PRJ File. Use this new coordinate system as target
  coordinate system in Project Tool.